# Java XML XPath Full XML

Tags: java, node.js, xml, xpath

got a little problem. I have the following code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse("result1.xml");
        XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//element");
        String elements = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

What i get :

```
        jcruz0@exblog.jp
        Cheryl
        Blake
        195115
```

What i want:

```
<person> 
  <email>jcruz0@exblog.jp</email>
  <firstname>Cheryl</firstname>
  <lastname>Blake</lastname>
  <number>195115</number> 
</person>
```

So as you can see i want the full XML tree. Not just the NodeValue.
Maybe somebody knows the trick.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You got the string value of the selected XML element because you specified `XPathConstants.STRING` to `XPathExpression.evaluate()`.

Instead, specify a return type of `XPathConstants.NODE` if you know for sure that your XPath will select a single element,

```
    String elements = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

or `XPathConstants.NODESET` for multiple elements, which you would then iterate over to process as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can be done.

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/person");
NodeList elements = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {
    // the person node
    System.out.println(elements.item(i).getNodeName());

    for (int x = 0; x < elements.item(i).getChildNodes().getLength(); x++) {
        // the elements under person
        if (elements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(x).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            System.out.println("\t" + elements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(x).getNodeName() + " - " + elements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(x).getTextContent());
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
person
    email - jcruz0@exblog.jp
    firstname - Cheryl
    lastname - Blake
    number - 195115
```

You can use the nodes to do what you want, or wrap them in `<` and `>` if you just want to print them.